# What is the number next to the character picture?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

When I hold <kbd>Down</kbd> on the D-Pad (Xbox) to show the character selection circle I notice there are some numbers next to the peoples faces. What do these numbers mean?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> You can easily check on how many “open” missions your three characters
>   have by pressing and holding the down button on the D-pad. When the
>   radial character switch interface appears, you’ll usually notice a
>   number over each character portrait. This number denotes how many
>   missions the character hasn’t yet started; if there’s no number, there
>   are no new missions to be collected.

http://www.digitaltrends.com/gaming/surviving-in-los-santos-a-guide-to-get-you-started-in-grand-theft-auto-v/